# Does using the detectMultiScale of the CascadeClassifier in opencv leak memory?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, opencv

As the title says. I'm trying to run a simple face detector on an image:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Mat image = imread("V2.jpg", 1);
  CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
  face_cascade.load("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
  vector<Rect> faces;
  face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, faces);
  return 0;
}
```

The following code, according to valgrind, leaks from the detectMultiScale function. Is there a good practice I'm neglecting here? Something to release? Logically, everything is on the stack from my end, so it should be released when the program ends.

valgrind's output is:

```
==4852==    at 0x4C28F9F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==4852==    by 0x4EB1D90: cv::fastMalloc(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3.1)
==4852==    by 0x58F175D: ??? (in /usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.3.1)
==4852==    by 0x58F8699: cvHaarDetectObjectsForROC(void const*, CvHaarClassifierCascade*, CvMemStorage*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, double, int, int, CvSize, CvSize, bool) (in /usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.3.1)
==4852==    by 0x58EA38B: cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >&, double, int, int, cv::Size_<int>, cv::Size_<int>, bool) (in /usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.3.1)
==4852==    by 0x58DA6B5: cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, double, int, int, cv::Size_<int>, cv::Size_<int>) (in /usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.3.1)
```

This is being run on a VMware VM running 64-bit Kubuntu 11.10 on Windows 7 64-bit. The OpenCV version is the latest - 2.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

You must release variable faces

Comment: isn't `faces` destroyed when it goes out of scope? and on destruction, the vector will call destructor of each object it holds. Or am I wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about the error message of Valgrind, but if there was a leak it sure is not in your code peace. Try to update to 2.4.2 though, it is much faster, too.